# /dev/disk/by-uuid/... does not exists - Fedora Server 38

Tags: fedora, partition, grub, uefi, fstab

I'm trying to get my Fedora Server from VirtualBox to USB drive.

I've used "VBoxManage clonehd blablabla --format raw" and then dd to copy the whole disk to USB drive. I did the same trick with Debian earlier and it worked. But with Fedora (with identical partition structure) for some reason I'm getting "/dev/disk/by-uuid/... does not exists" while trying to boot it.

I've checked, the UUID's of partitions on USB drive match those from /etc/fstab (namely they of course didn't change after flashing to USB drive). No LVM, no Btrfs, fstab points to UUIDs and not labels. Checksums are okay. No duplicates in UUID's either. Fedora is installed as EFI thing, not BIOS. The same as Debian before.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For some reason if you use second entry (for recovery) in the uefi boatloader it works perfectly.